# Error in sorting a list missing a cast

Tags: c#

i have a list that I am trying to sort by datetime and return it. but I get a   error.How do I fix this?

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<ConsoleApplication2.DTNBars>` to
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<ConsoleApplication2.DTNBars>`. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
public static List<DTNBars> getDTNBars(string symbol, DateTime dt)
{
    TextReader tr = new StreamReader(File.Open(@"C:\historicaldata\" + symbol + ".txt", FileMode.Open));
    List<DTNBars> dtnbars = new List<DTNBars>();

    CsvReader csvr = new CsvReader(tr);
    while (csvr.Read())
    {
        DTNBars b = new DTNBars();
        b.Date_Time = csvr.GetField<DateTime>(0);
        b.Open = csvr.GetField<double>(1);
        b.High = csvr.GetField<double>(2);
        b.Close = csvr.GetField<double>(4);
        b.Ticker = symbol;

        dtnbars.Add(b);
    }
    return dtnbars.OrderBy(x => x.Date_Time);
}

public  class  DTNBars     
{
    public DateTime Date_Time { get; set; }      
    public double Open { get; set; }
    public double High { get; set; }
    public double Low { get; set; }
    public double Close { get; set; }
    public string Ticker { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think all you need is to add a `ToList` after `OrderBy`.

Answer (score 2):

Use ToList()

```
 return dtnbars.OrderBy(x => x.Date_Time).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your method states a return type of `List<DTNBars>` but you are returning `IOrderedEnumerable<DTNBars>` - which is the result of the `OrderBy`. Add `ToList()`:

```
return dtnbars.OrderBy(x => x.Date_Time).ToList();
```

Or better just change return type to an `IEnumerable<DTNBars>`

---

Also you can refactor your initializing of the new `DTNBars` and use the object initializer:

```
dtnbars.Add( new DTNBars {
    Date_Time = csvr.GetField<DateTime>(0),
    Open = csvr.GetField<double>(1),
    High = csvr.GetField<double>(2),
    Close = csvr.GetField<double>(4),
    Ticker = symbol });
```